# What is the function of 的多 in 中国人爱喝茶的多?

Tags: grammar, usage

> 中国人爱喝茶的多。

I assume the meaning is that "Chinese people love drinking tea a lot", or "...really love drinking tea." Does 的多 act as an adverbial structure here? In what other situations would it be appropriate to use it? Would it be possible to say something like this...?

> "要努力的多!"

... or would that sound awkward?

Comment: I notice you have a 0% accept rate; consider marking a best answer here (and on other questions) when you're satisfied with a response.

Comment: About accepting answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Oops, that's terrible. I didn't realize I had to select a favourite answer. I'll fix that right away.

Comment: It's not mandatory, but it helps to identify useful content for other users!

Comment: @Benjameno You don't have to if there isn't a "correct" answer. Remember that if someone else posts a better answer someday, you can change the accepted answer if the new one is better for you and for your problem. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

中国人 is the topic of the sentence, which explains its position at the beginning. So, "As for Chinese people, ...".

爱喝茶的 is a nominalisation of 爱喝茶 "love to drink tea": hence "people who love to drink tea".

Finally, 多 is just the [stative verb](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/884/stative-verbs-in-chinese-only-for-adjectives) "many".

So, "Among Chinese people there are many who love to drink tea."

Comment: Another important detail: stative verbs without adverbial modifiers often imply comparison. Depending on context, 中国人爱喝茶的多 may have the sense "Among Chinese people, there are more who like to drink tea [than there are people of another type]." For example, "中国人爱喝茶的多，爱喝咖啡的少。"

Answer (score 2):

FYI, I speak Chinese.
中国人爱喝茶的多 is actually an incomplete sentence. The complete form should look like this:

> 比起美国人，中国人爱喝茶的多 or 中国人比美国人爱喝茶的多

So, 的多 can only be used in comparison, which means 'Far more than'.
And the sentence above means 'Chinese people love drinking tea far more than americans do'.

As for 中国人爱喝茶的多, you should learn it in the context, and find the other item in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Your two examples are using two different structures. For the first, see jogloran's answer.

In the second example you give, "的多" should be written as "得多". The meaning is "much more".

Your example can be translated as "much more hard-working". We can also say "好得多" (much better), "漂亮得多" (much more beautiful).