# When "to be" should be used? When omitted?

Tags: grammar

There are cases in which "to be" is translated with 是 ( shì ), while in some other cases it seems not to be translated at all.
When should 是 ( shì ) be used? When omitted?

Here some examples:
我很好
wo hen hao 
 I am very well

我是英国人
wǒ-shì-yīng-guó-rén
I am English

Wo hen kuai le
我 很快乐
I'm happy

我 25 岁 了
Wǒ èrshíwǔ suì le
I'm 25 years old

Disambiguation 1: I landed in a similar question: [When should I use the 是...的 construction?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/10492/11269) 
Note that it addresses the usage of 是 and的 !

Disambiguation 2: This question has been marked as oossible duplicate of: [Why is (是) shi4 dropped in this sentence："我很好"?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/q/6726/11269)

Indeed the subject is similar. I think that this question is more General, while the other targets a specific case (I was not able to find it before posting my question!). To be noted that some answers are quite similar.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is (是) shi4 dropped in this sentence："我很好"?](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/6726/why-is-%e6%98%af-shi4-dropped-in-this-sentence-%e6%88%91%e5%be%88%e5%a5%bd)

Comment: You never use `是` before an adjective as Chinese adjectives are also verbs so "good" also means "to be good". Often `很` seems to take the place of "to be" before an adjective though. I don't know if there are other words besides `很` that can do this or how and why and when it works and doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

是 in the first context is only used to say:

> Noun1 是 Noun2

You never say 我是很好, because 好 isn't a noun. You can say

> 我是美国人
>
> 他是男孩子
>
> 我是李红

because all those relate one noun to another. In the case of 我25岁了, 25 years old isn't a noun, it's a state, and so we don't use 是.

For a simple summary, 是 only relates 2 nouns to each other. If it's not a noun, don't use 是.

You can find more info and examples [here](http://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/ASGUN7RX#Structure), which I find is a good site for beginners to learn chinese, and gives lots of examples to help you understand.

Comment: 是 can also be used as "yes", which is a slightly different usage. You also here this usage in "是吗?", or phrases that use it.

Comment: An interesting thing to note is that dropping it in the case where it attaches two nouns would result in a scenario where one would assume an omitted 的.

Comment: Can I just ask, in '在小说兴旺的时候，这些媒介是没有的‘ ’没有的‘ is a noun??

Comment: @Pedroski that is another construct (…是…的), which is often used to emphasise.

Comment: @Pedroski The noun is omitted after the 的 since it`s retrieved by the context.

Comment: I was thinking that. So it is actually noun 是 noun, but the second noun has a stand in, the adjective, in my case above '没有的媒介‘。 Would you agree?